# EF 6 model from database, where do I put the context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6. I use it to generate my classes from an existing database. I am adding some fields and methods to these classes using another partial class. My question is about where shall I put the context.

i.e. I created a new constructor which take my context and create a new object and add it to the 
context:

```
public partial class EntityClass1
{
    private readonly EntitiesContext dbContext;
    private String customString1;
    private bool justInitialized;

    public EntityClass1(EntitiesContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        dbContext.EntityClass1.Add(this);
        customString1 = "voila";
        justInitialized = true;
    }

    public MethodUpdateString()
    {
        customString1 = "UPDATED";
        var entity2 = new EntityClass2();
        entity2.EntityClass1Id = this.Id;
        dbContext.EntityClass2.Add(entity2);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    {
}

public partial class EntityClass2
{
    //Some code here
}


public MainClass{
    static void Main(){
        using (var dbContext = new EntitiesContext())
        {
            //other operations on the context here

            var e1 = new EntityClass1(dbContext);
            e1.MethodUpdateString();   

            //other operations on the context here
        }  
    }
}
```

I don't why, but I am not really comfortable with this possible implementation. Will it better for example to add a context parameter to the method MethodUpdateString() ? Also because I do a SaveChamges I end the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your instincts are correct, both in trying to use constructor injection and in not being comfortable having data access logic inside your model class. An alternative implementation would be this:

```
public partial class EntityClass1Service
{
    private readonly EntitiesContext dbContext;

    public EntityClass1Service(EntitiesContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public MethodUpdateString(EntityClass1 entityClass1Object)
    {
        entityClass1Object.CustomString1 = "UPDATED";
        dbContext.EntityClass1.Add(entityClass1Object);
        var entity2 = new EntityClass2();
        entity2.EntityClass1Id = entityClass1Object.Id;
        dbContext.EntityClass2.Add(entity2);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You might also want to add a try-catch block inside the MethodUpdateString and maybe change `customString1` to be a public property.